# tikz: position label halfway along arrow shaft

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code draws an arrow from a to b with a label g.  The label looks like it is too far to the right, and not centered.

```
\[
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
 \node (b) at (1.2,0) {$b$};
 \draw[-open triangle 90] (a) to node {$g$} (b);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

The way to correct this in xymatrix is to add a dash before the label:

```
\[
  \xymatrix{a \ar[r]^-g & b}
\]
```

Is there a similar fix in tikz, or what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try `tikz-cd`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Notes:**

- The nodes in TikZ have a bigger inner seperator so that the arrow is slightly shorter than in the `xymatrix`.
- The `g` in the `xymatrix` is set in `\scriptstyle`. This does not apply automatically in TikZ, but can be achieved by settings the node’s content to `$\scriptstyle g$`.
- The difference between the `g` and the `-g` version in your `xymatrix` example is quite small:
  [image]
  [image]

  ---

For the placement of the node, there are many keys that help, mostly:

- `above` places the nodes content above the line-
- `pos` takes a value between `0.0` and `1.0` and means the relatively position between the start and the target.
- `auto` places the node automatically on one side and in the middle.

The automatically assigned `midway` (= `pos=.5`) is calculated for the whole arrow, not only the part that is not the arrow head. This is the reason it looks okay in `xymatrix` (the arrow head is quite small), but not so good if you use a big arrow like `open triangle 90` on such a short line.

### Solution for straight lines (`--`/`line to`) and fixed arrow

From the code for the `open triange 90` arrow one can see that its length is `6 (.5pt + .25\pgflinewidth)`. This length is subtracted from the placement of the node.

The trickery with the `name path` keys was necessary because `($(\tikztotarget)!6*(.5pt+.25\pgflinewidth)!(\tikztostart)$)` would have calculated from the centers not from the node’s border.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    calc,
    positioning,
    intersections,
}
\newcount\qrrArrowLineCounter
\newdimen\qrrArrowLength
\tikzset{
    name/.append style={
        /tikz/name path=qrr-node-#1
    },
    arrow length/.code={
        \pgfmathsetlength\qrrArrowLength{#1}
    },
    m/.style={
        arrow length=6*(.5pt+.25\pgflinewidth),
        to path={
            \pgfextra{
                \path[name path=qrr-\the\qrrArrowLineCounter-path] (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget);
                \path[name intersections={of=qrr-\the\qrrArrowLineCounter-path and qrr-node-\tikztostart}] (intersection-1) coordinate (qrr-\the\qrrArrowLineCounter-start);
                \path[name intersections={of=qrr-\the\qrrArrowLineCounter-path and qrr-node-\tikztotarget}] (intersection-1) coordinate (qrr-\the\qrrArrowLineCounter-target);
                \path (\tikztostart) -- ($(qrr-\the\qrrArrowLineCounter-target)!\the\qrrArrowLength!(qrr-\the\qrrArrowLineCounter-start)$) \tikztonodes;
                \global\advance\qrrArrowLineCounter by 1\relax
            }
            (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget)
        }
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) {$a$}; \node (b) at (1.2,0) {$b$};
    \draw[-open triangle 90] (a) -- node[above] {$\scriptstyle g$} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) {$a$}; \node (b) at (1.2,0) {$b$};
    \draw[-open triangle 90] (a) -- node[above left=0cm and 1.2pt,anchor=south] {$\scriptstyle g$} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[name=a] at (0,0) {$a$}; \node (b) at (1.2,0) {$b$};
    \draw[-open triangle 90] (a) to[m] node[above] {$\scriptstyle g$} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

Order:

- without any placement correction
- manual placement to the left (works only for horizontal left-to-right lines)
- automatically placement for nodes on straight lines

[image]

### Maybe `tikz-cd`

Although it does not solve the actual problem on hand, the package `tikz-cd` works similar to `xymatrix` but uses TikZ.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
    \node (b) at (1.2,0) {$b$};
    \draw[-open triangle 90] (a) -- node[auto] {$\scriptstyle g$} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
a \arrow{r}{g} & b \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: IMHO `xymatrix` is fancier. See the font size.

Comment: `$\scriptstyle g$`

Comment: @Sigur Although that was not the question, egreg pointed out how to achieve the same output as in `xymatrix`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I actually tried this, but it looked the same afterwards.  I admit my toy example isn't very good; my real problem is a little more complicated.  I don't really understand what's going on, but in xymatrix this kind of problem is very easy to resolve!  I think it has something to do with the fact that the label is placed half way between the nodes, whereas the eye expects to see it half way along the shaft.

Comment: @Alex I have updated my answer with a solution for straight lines and this specific arrow. For bent lines I can’t offer any placement corrections (tried similar things with the `markings` library).

Comment: can above shifted across y-axis?

Answer (score 6):

maybe is this what you looking for:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
 \node (b) at (1.2,0) {$b$};
 \draw[-open triangle 90] (a) to node[pos=0.45] {$g$} (b);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```