# Parabola starting at the node shape border

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to draw a parabola respecting the border shape of the node?
In a simple line or arc this is possible by using nodes with `inner sep` as endpoints, but the parabola doesn't care about this separation option.

Here is an example, which shows the difference. I would like to have the parabola like the arc.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=2mm] at (0.0,0.0) (p1) {};
  \node[draw=none] at (1.0,1.0) (p2) {};
  \node[circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=2mm] at (3.0,0.0) (p3) {};
  \draw[->] (p1) parabola bend (p2) (p3);
  \draw[->] (p1) -- (p3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I would suggest the `\path` command with `.. controls (point1) and (point2) ..` to solve your problem. `point1` and `point2` can be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it doesnt work for me, because this parabola is part of a more complicated command, were more than one parabola meet in one point (in my example: node p2).

Comment: What if you redraw the node (with white filling) at the end?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add a signature and thanks, the preferred way to show appreciation is to upvote good answers

Comment: Thats what I will do if there is no other solution. But, since Im using an arrow, the arrowhead would not be seen completely by doing this.

Comment: The slightly manual but less painful approach is to give node anchors `(p1.60)` and `(p3.120)` as the start and end coordinates. Otherwise you need to make a few nontrivial calculations.

Comment: Does it have to be a parabola?

Answer (score 5):

A bit clumsy solution, but for this particular case it works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle,fill=white,draw=black,minimum size=6mm] at (0.0,0.0) (p1) {};
  \coordinate (p2) at (1.0,1.0);
  \node[circle,fill=white,draw=black,minimum size=6mm] at (3.0,0.0) (p3) {};

  \path[name path=circle 1] (0,0) circle(3mm);
  \path[name path=circle 2] (3,0) circle(3mm);
  \path[name path=parabola] (p1) parabola bend (p2) (p3);
  \path[name intersections = {of = parabola and circle 1, name = pp1}];
  \path[name intersections = {of = parabola and circle 2, name = pp3}];

  \draw[->] (pp1-1) parabola bend (p2) (pp3-1);
  \draw[->] (p1) -- (p3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: There’s no need to use extra paths, you can use the `name path` option directly on the node.

Answer (score 4):

This is [JLDiaz’ approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96014/16595) hidden in a `to` path.

This is very similar to [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88567/16595) but without the use of a count(er) overwriting every previous path `qrr@parabola` and previous coordinates `qrr@parabola-start-1` and `qrr@parabola-target-1`.

The style `parabola` just forwards its argument to the `parabola` path operator.
You could even use `to[parabola={[bend pos=0.5] bend +(0,2)}]` (taken from the PGF manual).

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\tikzset{
    name/.append style={
        /tikz/name path={qrr@path-#1},
    },
    parabola/.style={
        to path={
            \pgfextra
                \path[name path=qrr@parabola] (\tikztostart) parabola #1 (\tikztotarget);
                \path[name intersections = {of = qrr@parabola and qrr@path-\tikztostart, name=qrr@parabola-start}];
                \path[name intersections = {of = qrr@parabola and qrr@path-\tikztotarget, name=qrr@parabola-target}];
            \endpgfextra
            (qrr@parabola-start-1) parabola #1 (qrr@parabola-target-1)
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle,fill=white,draw=black,minimum size=6mm] at (0.0,0.0) (p1) {};
  \coordinate (p2) at (1.0,1.0);
  \node[circle,fill=white,draw=black,minimum size=6mm] at (3.0,0.0) (p3) {};

  \draw[->, green] (p1) to[parabola=bend (p2)] (p3);
  \draw[->, red] (p3) to[parabola={bend (1,-1)}] (p1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that solves all my problems. By this it automatically adjusts to the size of the nodes.

Comment: @user25233 Good! Note that this fails, if you want to draw a parabola from or to a coordinate or a node-anchor, then the `parabola` style needs to be adjusted so that only the pure nodes will be used for the intersections algorithm.